# Postman and VSTS Inline Powershell return different values

Tags: rest, postman, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm running a query in both VSTS and Postman. In Postman, I use basic auth and my username and password entered. In VSTS I use an Inline Azure Powershell step. VSTS code:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8; api-version=4.0-preview.4" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

After I run the query in VSTS, I Write-Output $uri and copy that into Postman. In the body of the Postman query, I get "count": "1" and the values that I'm expecting. In VSTS, with the exact same query, I get "count": "0". What is causing the difference?

Sometimes, instead of a difference in "count", I get the same data but it isn't visible. In VSTS it will be "{@{id=532; name=TestBuild_2017.09.28..." and in Postman it will have all the data like "id", "name", and "createdOn" visible. Can I change the way it is viewed in VSTS to make it all visible?

The Uri is: https://xx.vsrm.visualstudio.com/xx/xx/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.0-preview.4&statusFilter=successful&$top=1&searchText=xx

Comment: What do you mean you're running it "In VSTS"? As part of an extension? During a build or deployment?

Comment: As Inline Azure Powershell as a build step. Updated post description too.

Comment: What's the actual REST API ($Uri)? Do you use the same account?

Comment: I updated the post with the Uri

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. Some queries still show count 0 in VSTS and 1 in Postman, but I found a workaround that doesn't use the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the `$` character is the key word in PowerShell, you need to escape it by using grave-accent `.

Using https://xx.vsrm.visualstudio.com/xx/xx/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.0-preview.4&statusFilter=successful&`$top=1&searchText=xx instead.